# Chumash/Tanakh with larger font

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, pentateuch-chumash

I've checked in person:

```
ArtScroll Chumash Stone Edition
ArtScroll Chumash Schottenstein Interlinear Complete in 1 Volume
Koren Steinsaltz Humash 2nd ed.
```

All of those books have a font that is too small for my eyes.

Would you please recommend a Chumash (or Tanakh) in Hebrew and English which also contains commentaries. All of it should be in a larger font size than those mentioned above.

Comment: Jewish Heritage for the Blind has large-print items; I think some are even free for those with a doctor's note about a medical condition. JewishHeritage.org

Comment: Check this link https://www.amazon.com/Chumash-Bereishis-Haftorahs-Large-Print/dp/1494860015

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The one option I know with commentary is the [Schottenstein Interlinear Chumashim in 5 volumes](https://www.artscroll.com/Books/9781422609385.html). Since they are printed over five volumes, the font is larger and they do have the same commentary as the classic Stone Chumash.

I would recommend seeing it in person as one person's larger font is too small for another.

Incidentally, artscroll's interlinear siddurim also have larger fonts than the classic versions.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some large-print editions.

- JPS Chumash (18 point): [here](https://jps.org/books/torah-large-print-edition/) ([ezra](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/11486/ezra) points out that this is English-only, but I'll leave it in in case it's useful)
- JPS Psalms: [here](https://www.barnesandnoble.com/w/the-book-of-psalms-jewish-publication-society-inc/1114134138;jsessionid=32FE80AE5CDF4D605C606ED715478613.prodny_store01-atgap05?ean=9780827607323)
- Koren Reader's Tanakh: [here](https://korenpub.com/products/the-koren-readers-tanakhleatherleaders)
- Koren Large Type Torah: [here](https://korenpub.com/products/the-koren-large-type-torahhardcoverleaders)
- Artscroll Chazzan Size Tanach: [here](https://artscroll.com/Books/9781422618493.html?gclid=CjwKCAiAo4OQBhBBEiwA5KWu_xupWG4dxaUhVN8hAm8eZkFQHOj7Z01ANoZzP2T_wVfWVv-peTX0hxoCzxcQAvD_BwE)

I don't believe any of the above have a commentary, but that's because they're sacrificing commentary space for text size.

Comment: The JPS is only in English

Comment: @ezra Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. Unfortunately all of the books except JSP are in Hebrew only, so there are no English comments there.